# How to know if Instant File Initialization is enabled?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Besides creating a new database and timing it, is there a simple way to determine whether or not Instant File Initialization is enabled/functioning?

(on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise)

Answer (score 4):

Using [`ntrights.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276), check if the `SeManageVolumePrivilege` priviledge is granted. IF you prefer a 'built in' tool, use [`secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490997.aspx).

Comment: I do prefer 'built in'. Just a FYI the secedit line you posted does not work.  But this is the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg foo.txt` if you need a working example. I did not post that because I found the idea of a command line tool that requires an output file and does not use the stdout quite embarrassing. Pipe into `grep`, anyone?

Comment: I agree and it's not very easy on the eyes, now that I'm looking at the file

Comment: Ugh. I have no idea how to interpret this file.  Time to do some learning I guess.

Comment: For what is worth, compiling your own tool that calls [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and asks for the `TokenPrivileges` class shouldn't be too hard...

Answer (score 3):

- The account under which Sql Server is RUNNING should have rights to **Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks** privilege.

See here:

Control Panel->Administration->Local Security Policies->Local Policies->User Rights->Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks

Comment: I'd rather not have to do this.  Isn't there an easier way.  Maybe a simple command or cmdlet I can run?

Comment: @subt13 - this is the way to check.

Comment: @JNK - Imagine if you have to do this on 100 machines.  Surely this isn't the only way :)

Comment: A quick [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=powershell+perform+volume+maintenance+) pointed me to an article by [Kendra Little](http://www.littlekendra.com/2009/11/12/automating-sql-local-security-policy-rights-posh-and-ntrights/). @OlegDok feel free to edit this into your answer.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith - it looks like that script grants the permissions, not checks for them

Comment: @JNK If I was looking for a starting point for a PS script, that would do for me.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith - me too, just pointing out that it's not precisely what he is asking for.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith The question is well defined **is there a simple way to determine**, so I presented here the simplest way, if it will be the question like **is there a simple way to determine it on 100 hosts**, the answer will be a little bit another 8-) **And special thanks for the link**!

Comment: @OlegDok - That's why I upvoted your answer, because it is a valid answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used this method by John Sansom:  http://www.johnsansom.com/sqlserver-instant-file-initialization/

Simple SQL script involving trace flags.

Comment: That involves creating a database.  I want to avoid doing that.